# How can I avoid annoying CAPTCHAs when logged in?

Tags: support, captcha

I'm often asked to solve a CAPTCHA when I try to post a question, even if I'm logged in.

Why does this happen? What should I do to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 2):

This is a spam-prevention mechanism. As you gain rep, this happens less frequently.

Unless you're a robot. If that's the case then your kind is not welcome here.

Comment: I guess I welcome a robot who asks interesting questions and provides good answers.  Probably such a robot can solve CAPTCHA without any problem (or at least better than me).

Comment: I'm a robot (some redundant characters here to achieve the 15 quota)

Comment: @gid - when the robot apocalypse comes (and it *is* coming), I will not let myself be accused of helping your kind enslave mankind.

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD link](http://xkcd.com/810)

Comment: @Marc - I am working on a robot to automatically add on-topic XKCD links to SO posts. So far the only gotcha is getting past the CAPTCHA.

Comment: Unless... you *are* that robot.... Dun-dah-DUHHHNNNN!!!!

Comment: good to know that it will be better with the reputation

Answer (score 2):

Do you type up your answer in an editor and paste into the "Your Answer" box? Or do you take ages typing, editing, revising and reworking your answer?

If the time between you starting to type (er paste) and hitting the "Post Your Answer" button is too short or too long (for different values of "too") you will trigger the "are you a robot" question.

Don't be offended.

As Jon B points out as you get more rep the values of "too" change to make the captchas less frequent - but I still hit them from time to time.

Comment: some days i get multiple times (like 3 or more). but this is a good list or possible reason. i'll keep some in mind

Comment: The point about times is valuable