# Stack Overflow keeps showing me CAPTCHAs when I try to search

Tags: bug, search, captcha

I'm trying to search Stack Overflow using Chrome 99.0.4844.82 on [Ubuntu 21.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_21.10_(Impish_Indri)) (Impish Indri), but I keep getting redirected to the CAPTCHA, even though I'm even logged in to Google.

[image: Screenshot from network tab]

[Screen recording of the issue](https://youtu.be/CXv_CClGRy4)

I'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: Sadly, DDoS attackers make it so we can't have nice things: [Search changes for anonymous users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355670/search-changes-for-anonymous-users). From the screen recording, it appears you're not logged into the Stack Overflow site itself.

Comment: clear out your cookies

Comment: If I have to be logged in to search, why does it show me the box or the captchas? It should then hide the search box or ask me to log in.

Comment: Clearing out the cookies seems to work for 1 search. After that I'm stuck again. Clearing out my cookies before each search doesn't seem very user friendly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Are you a human?" frequency hugely increased](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259605/282094)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138805/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70815/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329268/282094